# Sharepoint 2007 - Download Document Library to Local Drive

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server

We've got a Sharepoint 2007 server where I need to download the contents of an entire document library to a local drive.

What's the recommended approach to accomplish this in a scripted fashion?

Answer (score 2):

If you can log into the server as a administrator,

- use `PowerShell`, [here](http://chuvash.eu/2012/12/11/powershell-copy-an-entire-document-library-from-sharepoint-2007-to-disk/) is a link outlining how you can download the entire document library to a local drive
- use `stsadm`; [here](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/11/import-export-copy-and-delete-list-items/) is a blog post about how to use the `gl-exportlistitem` command

If you can't log into the server,

- use the MOSS 2007 web services, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2007/09/15/how-to-download-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-remotely-via-lists-asmx-webservice-sps-2003-moss-2007.aspx) is a blog post outlining that method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Explorer View.

Open the Library in Explorer View.

Drag and drop content to desktop/folder/etc.

Comment: Thanks but I need to script the process